# R in IBM Watson, I can't get packages to install because of Rcpp

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson

I am trying to load code into a notebook in Watson Studio Cloud.
HOwever, when I try to install packages and then make the library call I get the error below.  Does anyone know how I can resolve this?  I thought I had it taken care of earlier in the week but it keeps coming up each day.

Also, if I am in Watson Studio do you know of a way to store packages so I don't have to install each time a new kernel starts.

```
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE,repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("rvest", dependencies = TRUE,repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("dplyr",dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("qdap",dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("stringdist",dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("htmltab",dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("edgar",dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("tidytext",dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

`library(Rcpp)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(qdap)
library(stringdist)
library(htmltab)
library(edgar)
library(stringi)
library(tidytext)`

Error in value[3L]: Package ‘Rcpp’ version 0.12.13 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘Rcpp’ is imported by ‘xml2’ so cannot be unloaded

Traceback:

1. library(Rcpp)
2. tryCatch(unloadNamespace(package), error = function(e) {
   .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
   .         paste("Error in", deparse(cc)[1L], ": ")
   .     else "Error : "
   .     stop(gettextf("Package %s version %s cannot be unloaded:\n %s", 
   .         sQuote(package), oldversion, paste0(P, conditionMessage(e), 
   .             "\n")), domain = NA)
   . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[3L]
6. stop(gettextf("Package %s version %s cannot be unloaded:\n %s", 
   .     sQuote(package), oldversion, paste0(P, conditionMessage(e), 
   .         "\n")), domain = NA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was installing packages that were already installed by the admin of the cloud account.  This was causing conflicts.

I used find.package to locate existing packages already installed and when one was not found I installed it.

No further issues.